# Asterisk behaviour in creating links

Tags: bash, symlink, console, ln

I am trying to create symbolic links for a set of files.

Suppose I want to link all the files with the `pdf` extension from an `origin_directory` to my present directory.

Up to now I have this command:

```
ln -nfs origin_directory/*.pdf -t .
```

This works preatty nicely. The problem happens if I don't have any `pdf` file in my `origin_directory`, because in this case a file `*.pdf` is created in my present directory, and it is a broken link.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: have a look at `shopt -s nullglob`

Comment: Or better `shopt -s failglob`. This will stop the `ln` from running.

Comment: @richard could you provide a reference, please? Or just some more detail? I'm not a bash expert

Comment: It is in the bash manual `man bash`.

Answer (score 1):

on bash this would work

```
if [ -e origin_directory/*.pdf ] ; then ln -nfs origin_directory/*.pdf . ; fi
```

EDIT: In case you have too many files

```
if [ $(ls origin_directory/*.pdf | wc -l) -gt "0" ] ; then ln -nfs origin_directory/*.pdf . ; fi
```

Comment: actually [ -e origin_directory/*.pdf ] gives an error: `bash: [: too many arguments`

Comment: oh ! that many files. You can try the following if condition ---  if [ $(ls origin_directory/*.pdf | wc -l) -gt "0" ]

Comment: doing this I get the following output: `[18: command not found` where 18 is the number of files

Answer (score 1):

If using `bash`, then first run

```
shopt -s failglob
```

Or better, put in your `.bashrc`

Now whenever you do:

```
ln -nfs origin_directory/*.pdf -t .
```

It will succeed or fail (with an error message, and do nothing).

---

from manual

failglob   If  set,  patterns which fail to match filenames during pathname expansion result in an expansion error.

Comment: thanks. I just need this behaviour for this one time. Should I reuse `shopt` to get back the usual behaviour?

Comment: `shopt -u failglob` to disable.